# Calling Web API via angularjs returns strange data format

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I’ve created a web api, along with a database that is seeded upon build (MVC 5 web api project in Visual Studio 2015). I’ve included an angular controller that calls the web api, and passes the data to my view. I’m using the ng-repeat directive in order to iterate through my records (4 records total), but instead, it seems to be iterating through the packet itself (I may be wrong in using term ‘packet’ here). It’s a more low level iteration for sure, giving me a success code and whatnot. I’ve included the code.

Here's my controller

```
(function(app) {

var AlphaController = function($scope, $http) {
    
    $http.get("/api/alpha/")
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.message = "Seems in line...";
            $scope.alphas = data;
        });
};

app.controller("AlphaController", AlphaController);
}(angular.module("comasApp")));
```

Here's my view index.chtml

```
    @section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Client/Scripts/comasApp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Client/Scripts/AlphaController.js"></script>
}

<div data-ng-app="comasApp">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>COMAS 1.0</h1>
        <p class="lead">Comas with an ng-splash</p>

    </div>
    <div ng-controller="AlphaController">
        
        <br />
        
        <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="a in alphas">
                <td>Row Delimiter</td>
                <td>{{a.DcNumber}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code returns no data, but gives me 6 blank rows.
However, the following change to the code in my view sheds more light:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="a in alphas">
            <td>Row Delimiter</td>
            <td>{{a}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This is an image of the view once code executes:

[image]

As you can see, it does return Json formatted data, but it also returns some other stuff I'm not entirely familiar with.

Here's image of API returned in browser:

[image]

Comment: looks like response is returning array, and 1st element is the actual data you want, please post the entire response of web api

Comment: That's exactly what's happening, I'm just not sure why this array is being returned rather than the raw json. I added an image to the bottom of the post of the api in the browser, is that what you were asking for?

Comment: The first argument of the `then` function is the response is not the data, it is the response object. It happens to have 6 properties. What you want is the `data` property

Comment: ```.then(function (response) {
            $scope.alphas = response.data;
        });```

Comment: Pop-A-Stash and Luke,  worked like a charm my friends! Thank you very much I feel dum :)